# Extracting values of a list containing several dataframes with the condition that a specific column of the data frame is positive by lapply?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop, lapply

Dear Stackoverflow members, 
I am currently searching for a lapply command line to do the following:
I have a list with 95 data frames. 
Each data frame has 6 columns, where column 3 contains positive and negative values. The accodring values are in column 4. 
What I want to do now is to extract for each data frame the positive values of column 3 and the beloning values of column 4. 
I had in mind that there are 2 possibilities:
1) using the lapply command where I need a function (which I am so far not able to create) or
2) using a for loop which is not working like i want to do it.

It would be wonderful if you could help me with that. 
I whish you a nice weekend, 
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dataframes are called `df1`, `df2` etc, we can get them in a list using `mget`, select rows with positive values in 3rd column and select 3rd and 4th column.

```
list_df <- lapply(mget(paste0('df', 1:95)), function(df) 
                 subset(df, df[[3]] > 0, select = 3:4))
```

If the data is already in the list, we can do :

```
list_df <- lapply(All_data, function(df) subset(df, df[[3]] > 0, select = 3:4))
```

Comment: Dear Mr. Shah, thank you very much for your very fast response. I only have another question: All my dataframes are inside a liste, called "AllData" and is in the envrionment with other lists which are preivous ones of "AllData". How can i tell the lapply function that i want to extract it from "AllData"? Thank you so much for your help! and kind regards, Chris